# Memory Corruption with getenv/putenv on VS2012

Tags: c, environment-variables, visual-studio-2012

I seem to be getting memory corruption when trying to run the following code compiled in VS2012.

It works fine in VS2010 and previous:

```
char *var1 = getenv("var1");  // Value for var1 is correct here

char var2S[MAXSTRING];

sprintf(var2S, "VAR2=%s/a/%s/b", var1, getValue());  //Var2 looks correct

static const char *env_string = strdup(const_cast<char *>(var2S));

putenv((char *)env_string); // Value for var1 is corrupt after this call
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getenv()` returns a pointer into the process global copy of the environement. From MSDN:

> getenv and _putenv use the copy of the environment pointed to by the global variable _environ to access the environment

So `var1` points inside that set of data.  Once you call `putenv()`, that global data is modified, and the `var1` pointer is pointing at changed memory.  You'll need to copy the data `var1` points to into your own buffer for modifying the environment, or call `var1 = getenv("var1")` again to 'refresh' the pointer.

Note that in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301602/12711) you indicate that using `getenv_s()` fixes the problem for you.  That's becuase `getenv_s()` copies the environement string into a buffer you provide instead of returning a pointer inthe gloabl `_environ` state that may change later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I did not read the docs closely enough on this one.

Comment: You kind of have to read between the lines.  However, in general any function that returns a pointer that you don't have to 'dispose of' somehow (or isn't related to a pointer that you passed in) often means that the function is returning a pointer to a static block that will get reused by a subsequent function call.  You should be immediately suspicious of reuse issues regarding that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with either of the [deprecated] calls to getenv, putenv, or strdup.

Changing to getenv_s and putenv_s, eliminated the need for strdup and also fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello getenv() works on a static memory, 2 calls one after one overide first call memory.
Thus retrieve the result in your own allocated variable:

```
char a[512];
char b[512];

strcpy(a, getenv("a"));
strcpy(b, getenv("b"));
printf("a=[%s]\n", a);
printf("b=[%s]\n", b);
```